# converting tuples to lists in python3 and modifying

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, tuples, python-3.4

This is python 3.

Lets say I have a tuple

```
tup = (1, 2, 3)
```

And this tuple is stored in a list:

```
a = []
a[0] = tup
```

I am iterating over the list `a`. What I need to do is modify the contents of `tup`. That is, I want to change the values, while keeping it in the list `a`. 
Is this correct?

```
tmp = list(a[0])
tmp[0] = 0 # Now a[0] = (0, 2, 3)
```

Furthermore: I am aware tuples are designed to be immutable, and that a list is probably better for `tup` instead of a tuple. However, I am uncomfortable using `append` to add elements to the list: the list is storing elements of a fixed size, and a tuple is a better representative of this. I'd rather add things manually to the list like `tup[0] = blah` than `tup.append(blah)`

Comment: You seem to have some misconceptions about lists: `a[0] = tup` -> `IndexError: list assignment index out of range`. You _must_ use `a.append(tup)` (or preallocate the list with `a = [None]`). Also, the only way to change an immutable item in a list — like a tuple — is to replace it with another.

Comment: yup, the debugger made me fix that. thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this is simple. You can't, and it doesn't make any sense to do so. Lists are mutable, tuples are not. If you want the elements of `a` to be mutable, have them as lists, eg, `a = [[1,2,3],...]`.

If you really wanted to have them as tuples, but change them, you could do something along the lines of a[0] = (0,)+a[0][1:]. This would create a *new* tuple in the list, and would be less efficient than just using a list of lists.

> Furthermore: I am aware tuples are designed to be immutable, and that a list is probably better for tup instead of a tuple.

It is.

> However, I am uncomfortable using append to add elements to the list: the list is storing elements of a fixed size, and a tuple is a better representative of this.

I'm not sure what you mean by this. Do you mean that `a` is a fixed size, or elements of `a` are a fixed size? In either case, how does this make tuples better?

The confusion here might be that lists in Python are not lists in a computer science sense; they are actually arrays. They are O(1) for retrieval, O(1) for setting elements, and usually O(1) for appends unless they need to be resized.

> I'd rather add things manually to the list like tup[0] = blah than tup.append(blah)

You *can't* do that with a tuple, but you can do *either* with a list, and they're both around O(1).

If you really want fixed-size, mutable arrays, you could look at numpy, or you could initialize python lists of set sizes.